# How to integrate AMF in ios app

Tags: objective-c, amfphp

i am new-bee for AMFClient integration in ios app. if any one have good tutorial please share it with me. i appreciate your help in advance.

thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you want to use this lib:
https://github.com/nesium/cocoa-amf 
I can't seem to find a tutorial though.

Comment: hi Ariel, Thanks for your help but in this tutorial AMFClient Code contains some some errors and some files missing. i want to integrate with  AMFClient in ios app.